# After saving formfield input to an sqflite DB, the entry doesn't show on the overview screen. It does show after hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

ello folks,

I am rather new to Flutter, but eager to learn, and I would be genuinely grateful for a solution or advise. The code is partially stitched together, partially my own.

I'm working on a simplified diary, with a standard couple of standard questions to fill in.

Basic layout

- opening screen with floating action button to write a new entry. This page also shows previous entries with a future Listviewbuilder.
- add entry screen with textfields. Upon saving an entry, or editing an update, the user will go back to the opening screen. However, new entries are not shown, nor are updates to previous entries, **until I hit hot reload.**

My guess (made with rather limited -if we can call it that- experience) is i'm missing something with the state management. The code looks horrible, and there are a million things I like to do to make it shorter, and more succinct. However, firstly I like to get it to function properly.

code for add entry screen:

```
class AddCircleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/AddCircleScreen';
  final Circle circle;

  const AddCircleScreen({Key key, this.circle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddCircleScreenState createState() => _AddCircleScreenState(circle);
}

//TODO: Refactor widgets below
class _AddCircleScreenState extends State<AddCircleScreen> {
  Circle circle;
  final gebeurtenisTextController = TextEditingController();
  final gevoelTextController = TextEditingController();
  final gedachtenTextController = TextEditingController();
  final gedragTextController = TextEditingController();
  final gevolgTextController = TextEditingController();
  final toelichtingTextController = TextEditingController();

  _AddCircleScreenState(this.circle);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (circle != null) {
      gebeurtenisTextController.text = circle.gebeurtenis;
      gevoelTextController.text = circle.gevoel;
      gedachtenTextController.text = circle.gedachten;
      gedragTextController.text = circle.gedrag;
      gevolgTextController.text = circle.gevolg;
      toelichtingTextController.text = circle.toelichting;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    gebeurtenisTextController.dispose();
    gevoelTextController.dispose();
    gedachtenTextController.dispose();
    gedragTextController.dispose();
    gevolgTextController.dispose();
    toelichtingTextController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: (Colors.yellow[100]),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: (Colors.green[400]),
        title: Center(
          child: Text('Small steps...'),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Gebeurtenis',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Beschrijf kort de situatie'),
                controller: gebeurtenisTextController,
              ),
            ),
          The above code times 6, for all the different textfields.
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: Icon(Icons.check),
          onPressed: () async {
            _saveCircle(
              gebeurtenisTextController.text,
              gevoelTextController.text,
              gedachtenTextController.text,
              gedragTextController.text,
              gevolgTextController.text,
              toelichtingTextController.text,
            );
            setState(() {});
          }),
    );
  }

  _saveCircle(String gebeurtenis, String gevoel, String gedachten,
      String gedrag, String gevolg, String toelichting) async {
    if (circle == null) {
      DatabaseHelper.instance.insertCircle(Circle(
          gebeurtenis: gebeurtenisTextController.text,
          gevoel: gevoelTextController.text,
          gedachten: gedachtenTextController.text,
          gedrag: gedragTextController.text,
          gevolg: gevolgTextController.text,
          toelichting: toelichtingTextController.text));
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      await DatabaseHelper.instance.updateCircle(Circle(
          id: circle.id,
          gebeurtenis: gebeurtenis,
          gevoel: gevoel,
          gedachten: gedachten,
          gedrag: gedrag,
          gevolg: gevolg,
          toelichting: toelichting));
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}
```

code for opening screen:

```
class CircleOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CircleOverviewScreenState createState() => _CircleOverviewScreenState();
}

class _CircleOverviewScreenState extends State<CircleOverviewScreen> {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cirkels'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Circle>>(
        future: DatabaseHelper.instance.retrieveCircles(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].gebeurtenis),
                  leading: Text(snapshot.data[index].id.toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].gevolg),
                  onTap: () =>
                      _navigateToAddCircleScreen(context, snapshot.data[index]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        _deleteTodo(snapshot.data[index]);
                        setState(() {});
                      }),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("Je hebt nog geen 5G'tjes opgeslagen"));
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Icon(Icons.create_sharp),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => AddCircleScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_deleteTodo(Circle circle) {
  DatabaseHelper.instance.deleteCircle(circle.id);
}

_navigateToAddCircleScreen(BuildContext context, Circle circle) async {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddCircleScreen(circle: circle)),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to refresh you screen is to call [`setState()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) when the `AddCircle` screen is popped. You can do this when the `Future` returned by [`Navigator.push()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) completes.

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => AddCircleScreen(),
  ),
).then((_) => setState(() {})),
```

In the long run you should learn to use A [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) widget and proper [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) to solve this kind of problem.

I'm sure you'll enjoy working with apps this way!

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply! I've tried adding the code as you suggested, but hit a new error: The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(dynamic)'. Perhaps I'm just a tad bit too far out of my league, but if you would be able to help me some more, that would be great!

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I forgot to include the value argument in the closure that's given to the then() function. Since this value is not needed, it is enough to use and undescore "_", which typically is used for unused args in closures. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am really grateful. The update you've sent works; at least to certain degree. On writing a new entry this works; it updates the overviewscreen. When editing an existing entry, it still behaves the same, the overview screen won't update. I would understand if you don't have other suggestions to offer, but if you do... :-)